# Change JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

I use the following code to get content from my table.
But I need to change the output of the JSON a little bit.

```
$rows = array();
if(isset($_GET['fruitName'])) {
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT variety FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY variety");
$stmt->execute(array($_GET['fruitName']));
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

With the above code it show it like this:

```
[{"variety":"Apple"},{"variety":"Banana"},{"variety":"Orange"},{"variety":"Pear"}]
```

But I want it to be like this:

```
[{"optionValue": "Apple", "optionDisplay": "Apple"}, {"optionValue": "Banana", "optionDisplay": "Banana"}, {"optionValue": "Orange", "optionDisplay": "Orange"}, {"optionValue": "Pear", "optionDisplay": "Pear"}]
```

Comment: Wait, what you're asking for is adding spaces? What's the point of that? If you need your compressed string presented in a way a human can read it better, just google for json formatter and format your string there.

Comment: No, forget the space. I need to add the text: optionValue and optionDisplay with the same value from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution could be to adjust the SQL-query like this:

```sql
SELECT variety AS optionValue, variety AS optionDisplay FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY variety
```

Another approach would be to parse each row individually and build up your array by hand. So instead of

```php
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

you could use

```php
$rows = array();
while( $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  $rows[] = array( 'optionValue' => $row['variety'], 'optionDisplay' => $row['variety'] );
}
```

Comment: I think I will adjust my SQL-query. Thanks Sirko

Answer (score 0):

Change your select statement to

```
"SELECT variety as `optionValue`,variety as `optionDisplay` FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY variety"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = '[{"variety":"Apple"},{"variety":"Banana"},{"variety":"Orange"},{"variety":"Pear"}]';

$arr = new array();
// loop through the data
foreach($data as $k => $v){
  // build an array of values formatted as you want
  $arr[] = '{"optionValue": "'.$v.'", "optionDisplay": "'.$v.'"}}';
}
// join all the values togetger, and pass through json parser
$obj = json_decode(',', "[" . implode($arr) . "]");
// should return in your desired format...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, as I can't test this, but couldn't you change your SQL statement to:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT variety as optionValue, variety as optionDisplay FROM fruit WHERE name = ? ORDER BY optionDisplay");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would wanna do this, but anyways, this is how:

```
$new_array=array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
array_push($new_array,array("optionValue"=>$row['variety'],"optionDisplay"=>$row['variety']));
}
echo json_encode($new_array);
```